# Can I selectively enforce 2FA with FreeIPA

Tags: freeipa

I'm running FreeIPA 4.6.6 on Centos 7. However I only want to enforce 2FA (password + OTP) for members of a specific ldap group? Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

No, 2FA handling in FreeIPA does not work this way. The enforcement is done either globally or defined per-user. There is no group-based policy that would enforce 2FA requirement for a user. It also depends on whether user already has a token or not.

If you can describe a use case for group-based enforcement, please file a ticket at https://pagure.io/freeipa/new_issue. It would be good to understand what are practical needs here.

Comment: I created Issue # 8380.

Comment: But essentially if 2FA could be selectively applied, a user would log into a VPN client with their password + OTP token. Once authenticated and a VPN connection is established, the user would then be able to log into internal applications using only their password.

Comment: Thanks. Note that what you described in the ticket is harder to implement. Regardless which app tries to authenticate user to LDAP (with LDAP bind), the authentication itself would look the same, so it is technically not possible to differentiate them.
There is currently a work to enable application-specific passwords upstream, so may be we'll see if that can be coerced into this use case once done.